# Powershell - Verify column names in csv

Tags: powershell, csv

For a SQL import from a csv file via PS I need to check if the columns in the csv are the correct name. The following function tells me I'm missing all columns in my csv file.

```
Powershell Function CheckCSVColumnsExist
    {
    Param(
        [Object]$CSVImportFile,
        [Array]$ColumnsToCheck = ''
        )
    $c = (get-content $CSVImportFile | Select-Object -First 2) | ConvertFrom-CSV
    $ColumnHeaders = $c.psobject.properties.name
    foreach ($ctc in $ColumnsToCheck){
        if ($ColumnHeaders -notcontains $ctc){
            [array]$MissingColumnName += [PSCustomObject]@{Column_Name = $ctc}
        }
    }
    $MissingColumnName
}
```

Executing Powershell command:

```
CheckCSVColumnsExist $WorkspaceCSV "column1","column2","column3","column4","column5","column6","column7","column8","column9"
```

CSV content:

```
column1,column,column3,column4,column5,column6,column7,column8,column9
A11111 A111,A111/11,A111,Test Partner,11,A111,DAA,D Test,01/01/1970
```

Comment: `$ColumnHeaders = (@(Get-Content $CSVImportFile |Select-Object -First 1) * 2 |ConvertFrom-Csv).PSObject.Properties.Name`

Comment: If you just want to see what Import-Csv does with your file,  do this test:  
Import-Csv myfile.csv | Format-Table.  That will show you the column names from what it thinks is the header.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're trying to read column names from the first data row returned by `ConvertFrom-Csv` (and `Import-Csv`) but they don't return *anything* if there's **just a header row in the source csv text** (which is what you have).

You can see this with:

```
$tmp = "column1,column2,column3,column4,column5,column6,column7,column8,column9"
Set-Content -Path "c:\temp\my.csv" -Value $tmp

$headers = Get-Content -Path "c:\temp\my.csv" | Select-Object -First 1
$data = $headers | ConvertFrom-Csv

$null -eq $data
# True
```

What you *could* do is take the first row of the csv file and append a dummy data row:

```
$tmp = "column1,column2,column3,column4,column5,column6,column7,column8,column9"
Set-Content -Path "c:\temp\my.csv" -Value $tmp

$headers = Get-Content -Path "c:\temp\my.csv" | Select-Object -First 1
$data = $headers + "`r`naaa" | ConvertFrom-Csv
#                  ^^^^^^^^^ append a dummy data row

$null -eq data
# False

$data
# column1 : aaa
# column2 :
# column3 :
# column4 :
# column5 :
# column6 :
# column7 :
# column8 :
# column9 :
```

and then the rest of your function will be able to read the object properties.

**But watch out!** because csv column names can contain line breaks, and then it all starts to go a bit wrong:

```
$tmp = "column1,column2,column3,`"column`r`n4`",column5,column6,column7,column8,column9"
#                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ quoted column name with line breaks
Set-Content -Path "c:\temp\my.csv" -Value $tmp

$headers = Get-Content -Path "c:\temp\my.csv" | Select-Object -First 1
$headers
# column1,column2,column3,"column

$data = $headers + "`r`naaa" | ConvertFrom-Csv

$null -eq $data
# True
```

but maybe that's not going to be a problem with your data and this might be "good enough".

If not, there are various 3rd party libraries that you could `Add-Type` with that can process csv files that you could look at which let you read the column names even if there's only a header row in the data...

Comment: Hi Mclayton, Thank you for your response. The CSV file has content in it.
Cant share because of sensitive data. 
When i change column2 to column it gives back true which it shouldn't: 
column1,column,column3,column4,column5,column6,column7,column8,column9
A11111 A111,A111/11,A111,Test Partner,11,A111,DAA,D Test,01/01/1970

Comment: @Dave - you should update the csv sample in your original question rather than in a comment here - others might not read this far down the page before they spend time trying to solve your problem...

Answer (score 0):

I think I have found a solution:

```
Function CheckCSVColumnsExist
    {
    Param(
        [Object]$CSVImportFile,
        [Array]$ColumnsToCheck = ''     
        )
    $ColumnHeaders = (Import-Csv $CSVImportFile | Get-Member -MemberType NoteProperty).Name
    $MissingColumnHeaders = @()
    ForEach( $ColumnToCheck in $ColumnsToCheck)
        {
        $MissingColumnName = New-Object PSObject
        If ($ColumnHeaders.Contains($ColumnToCheck) ) 
            {
            # Nothing to do.
            } 
        Else 
            {
            $MissingColumnName | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -Name 'Column_Name' -Value $ColumnToCheck
            }
        $MissingColumnHeaders += $MissingColumnName
        }
    Return $MissingColumnHeaders
    }
```

Complete code for importing CSV into SQL

```
$LogFile="C:\CSVImport\Logs\CSVImports.log";
$WorkspaceCSV  = "C:\CSVImport\test.csv";

$sqlServer = "";
$sqlDb = "";
$sqlTable = "";
$SQLUsername = "";
$SQLPassword = "";



function WrDLine {
  param([string]$CH);
  $($CH*$LR) | Out-File -FilePath $LogFile -Append;
}

function WrDText {
  param([string]$STR);
  $STR | Out-File -FilePath $LogFile -Append;
}

#logwrite function to write output to log file
Function LogWrite([string]$logstring,[string]$fileLog)
    {
   #Param ([string]$logstring,[string]$fileLog)
   
   Add-content $WorkspaceCSV -value $logstring
    }



#Execute SQL query (Uses .NET, No SQL Server installs required!)
function Invoke-SQL 
    {
    param(
        [string] $sqlCommand = $(throw "Please specify a query.")
        )

    if ($SQLUsername -eq "") 
    {
        $connectionString = "Data Source=$sqlServer; " + "Integrated Security=SSPI; " +"Initial Catalog=$sqlDb"
    }
    else {
        $connectionString = "Data Source=$sqlServer;Initial Catalog=$sqlDb;User Id=$SQLUsername; Password=$SQLPassword;Connection Timeout=600;"
    }

    $connection = new-object system.data.SqlClient.SQLConnection($connectionString)
    $command = new-object system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand($sqlCommand,$connection)
    $connection.Open()

    $adapter = New-Object System.Data.sqlclient.sqlDataAdapter $command
    $dataset = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
    $adapter.Fill($dataSet) | Out-Null

    $connection.Close()
    return $dataSet.Tables
    WrDText("$(Get-Date -Format G) Inserted $CSVRowCount rows from CSV into SQL Table $sqlDb.$sqlTable");

}

#check missing columns in CSV before removing data from Staging table
Function CheckCSVColumnsExist
    {
    Param(
        [Object]$CSVImportFile,
        [Array]$ColumnsToCheck = ''     
        )

    $ColumnHeaders = (Import-Csv $CSVImportFile | Get-Member -MemberType NoteProperty).Name
    $MissingColumnHeaders = @()
    ForEach( $ColumnToCheck in $ColumnsToCheck)
        {
        $MissingColumnName = New-Object PSObject
        If ($ColumnHeaders.Contains($ColumnToCheck) ) 
            {
            # Nothing to do.
            } 
        Else 
            {
            $MissingColumnName | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -Name 'Column_Name' -Value $ColumnToCheck
            }
        $MissingColumnHeaders += $MissingColumnName
        }
    Return $MissingColumnHeaders
    }




##############################################
# Importing workspace CSV data
##############################################
$CSVImport = @(Import-CSV $WorkspaceCSV -encoding UTF7);
$CSVRowCount = $CSVImport.Count

if (($CSVRowCount -gt 0) -and (CheckCSVColumnsExist $WorkspaceCSV "column1","column2","column3","column4","column5","column6","column7","column8","column9"))
{
    # ForEach CSV Line Inserting a row into the staging SQL table
    write-host "Inserting $CSVRowCount rows from CSV into SQL Table $sqlDb.$sqlTable";
    WrDText("$(Get-Date -Format G) Inserting $CSVRowCount rows from CSV into SQL Table $sqlDb.$sqlTable");

    # Clear SQL Table
    $Clearsql = "Delete FROM $sqlDb.$sqlTable";
    Invoke-SQL $Clearsql


    ForEach ($CSVLine in $CSVImport)
    {
        # Setting variables for the CSV line
        $workspaceid = $CSVLine.column2
        $library = "Test"
        $wsname = $CSVLine.column1
        $custom1 = $CSVLine.column3
        $custom2 = $CSVLine.column5
        $custom3 = $CSVLine.column7
        $custom4 = "UK"
        $c1desc = $CSVLine.column4
        $c2desc = $CSVLine.column6
        $c3desc = $CSVLine.column8
        $c4desc = "United Kingdom"
        $CDate1 = $CSVLine.column9
        $insertdate = Get-Date -Format G
        $tries  = "0"
        

        ##############################################
        # SQL INSERT of CSV Line/Row
        ##############################################
        $SQLInsert = "INSERT INTO $sqlDb.$sqlTable ([WorkspaceID],[Library],[Name],[C1Alias],[C2Alias],[C3Alias],[C4Alias],[C1Desc],[C2Desc],[C3Desc],[C4Desc],[CDate1],[InsertDate],[Tries])
                        VALUES('$workspaceid', '$library', '$wsname', '$custom1', '$custom2', '$custom3', '$custom4', '$c1desc', '$c2desc', '$c3desc', '$c4desc', '$CDate1', '$insertdate', '$tries')";
        #$SQLInsert
        # Running the INSERT Query
        Invoke-SQL $SQLInsert
        
    } #End of ForEach CSV line
}
    else 
    {
     write-host "The CSV has 0 rows or the column names have been changed check $WorkspaceCSV";
     WrDText("$(Get-Date -Format G) The CSV has 0 rows or the column names have been changed check $WorkspaceCSV");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If indeed your csv has data, you can change your function into something like this:

```
function CheckCSVColumnsExist {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 0)]
        [string]$CSVImportFile,
        [string[]]$ColumnsToCheck = $null
    )
    $firstRow = (Import-Csv -Path $CSVImportFile)[0]
    $ColumnHeaders = $firstRow.PsObject.Properties.Name
    # return an array of missing column headers
    ,@($ColumnHeaders | Where-Object { $ColumnsToCheck -notcontains $_ } )
}

$WorkspaceCSV = 'D:\Test\data.csv'
$missing = CheckCSVColumnsExist $WorkspaceCSV "column1","column","column3","column4","column5","column6","column7","column8","column9"
if ($missing.Count) {
    Write-Host ('Missing headers: {0}' -f ($missing -join ';'))
}
else {
    Write-Host 'All columns correct' -ForegroundColor Green
}
```

<sup>In the above, I added a deliberate mistake with `"column"` where in the csv file this is called `"column2"` to show output:</sup>

```
Missing headers: column2
```